# Ever-changing nationalities

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography, history

> Make me Portuguese, and I live next door.
>   Make me Spanish, and I live in the same building.
>   Make me British, and I live far away.
>   Make me Dutch, and I live next door from there.
>   Make me French, and I'm back where I started.

Who am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you

> Guinea?

Make me Portuguese, and I live next door.

> Portuguese Guinea was right next door to Guinea.

Make me Spanish, and I live in the same building.

> The Spanish owned what is now called Equatorial Guinea (same building/continent).

Make me British, and I live far away.

> British Guinea is Papua New Guinea, in the Pacific Ocean, far away from Africa.

Make me Dutch, and I live next door from there.

> Dutch Guinea is another territory in the Pacific Ocean, the Papua region of Indonesia. This is next door to British Guinea.

Make me French, and I'm back where I started.

> French Guinea is now the country of Guinea.

Comment: This is very close.

Comment: @jafe I think this might be more correct...now that my answer is a little more specific.

Comment: This is it :) Although the French one is not G-B but just G, right?

Comment: That is correct! Fixed now. Thanks @jafe!!

Answer (score 5):

> French Guiana

Make me Portuguese, and I live next door.

> Next to Brazil, ex-Portuguese colony

Make me Spanish, and I live in the same building.

> A lot of ex-Spanish colonies in South America

Make me British, and I live far away.

> Apart from a few Carribean islands, Great Britain is quite far

Make me Dutch, and I live next door from there.

> Suriname is in the place of the former Dutch colony, Surinam

Make me French, and I'm back where I started.

> And back to French Guiana

Comment: I like the answer of [r13(gur Thvnanf)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guianas) although the Spanish one is on the opposite side from the Portuguese and French ones, and is actually farther away than the British one; [see map here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guianas#/media/File:Guyanas.svg)

Comment: You have the right idea, but this is not the intended answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> a Frenchman?

Because

> *Make me French, and I'm back where I started.* - before you were made Portugese in the riddle, you were French.
>  I am aware that my solution does not match the other parts but based on your last line you had to be a frenchman.